# CORS issue for Resource Server

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, cors, scalability

I am working on Spring boot application(WebServices) with
    authorization server and resource server So I want to use the services 
     I created Angularjs Project.

I am able to login to the authorization server but unable to access the
    resource services. I attached the screen shot of the CORS error message  [here](http://postimg.org/image/r1i789wvd/) please go through it

I have created Sample Projects in the Github those links are

1) For Sample Spring application click on this [Link](https://github.com/karthikpamidimarri/Oauth-Resource-Servers)

2) For Sample Angularjs application click on  this [Link](https://github.com/karthikpamidimarri/Login-Oauth-Resource-Servers)

Thanks in advance

Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply because you have specified Access-control-allowed-origin twice in the system in both of this file.

```
OAuthConfiguration.java
SimpleCORSFilter.java
```